# Big difference in time to delete from postgres temp tables

Tags: postgresql

I had a query that was taking a long time to run and so I re-wrote it and now it takes almost no time at all to run - but I don't understand why.

I can understand a small difference, but can someone help explain the massive difference in time taken to run these two (seeming very similar) statements?

First:

```
DELETE FROM     t_old where company_id not in (select company_id from t_prop);
```

Second:

```
DELETE FROM     t_old a
using           t_prop b 
where           a.company_id=b.company_id
and             b.company_id is null;
```

Execution plan from first:

```
'[
  {
    "Plan": {
  "Startup Cost": 0,
  "Plans": [
    {
      "Filter": "(NOT (SubPlan 1))",
      "Startup Cost": 0,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Startup Cost": 0,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Startup Cost": 0,
              "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
              "Plan Rows": 158704,
              "Relation Name": "t_prop",
              "Alias": "t_prop",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Plan Width": 4,
              "Total Cost": 2598.04
            }
          ],
          "Node Type": "Materialize",
          "Plan Rows": 158704,
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Parent Relationship": "SubPlan",
          "Plan Width": 4,
          "Subplan Name": "SubPlan 1",
          "Total Cost": 4011.56
        }
      ],
      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
      "Plan Rows": 21760,
      "Relation Name": "t_old",
      "Alias": "t_old",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Parent Relationship": "Member",
      "Plan Width": 6,
      "Total Cost": 95923746.03
    }
  ],
  "Node Type": "ModifyTable",
  "Plan Rows": 21760,
  "Relation Name": "t_old",
  "Alias": "t_old",
  "Parallel Aware": false,
  "Operation": "Delete",
  "Plan Width": 6,
  "Total Cost": 95923746.03
}
```

}
]'

Execution plan from second

```
'[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Startup Cost": 0.71,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Startup Cost": 0.71,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Startup Cost": 0.42,
              "Scan Direction": "Forward",
              "Plan Width": 10,
              "Node Type": "Index Scan",

          "Index Cond": "(company_id IS NULL)",
          "Plan Rows": 1,
          "Relation Name": "t_prop",
          "Alias": "b",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Total Cost": 8.44,
          "Index Name": "t_prop_idx2"
        },
        {
          "Startup Cost": 0.29,
          "Scan Direction": "Forward",
          "Plan Width": 10,
          "Node Type": "Index Scan",
          "Index Cond": "(company_id = b.company_id)",
          "Plan Rows": 5,
          "Relation Name": "t_old",
          "Alias": "a",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
          "Total Cost": 8.38,
          "Index Name": "t_old_idx"
        }
      ],
      "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
      "Plan Rows": 5,
      "Join Type": "Inner",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Parent Relationship": "Member",
      "Plan Width": 12,
      "Total Cost": 16.86
    }
  ],
  "Node Type": "ModifyTable",
  "Plan Rows": 5,
  "Relation Name": "t_old",
  "Alias": "a",
  "Parallel Aware": false,
  "Operation": "Delete",
  "Plan Width": 12,
  "Total Cost": 16.86
}
```

}
]'

Comment: You can see from the explain plan that the second query uses an index scan, which is a lot faster.

Comment: join is most often faster then `IN` subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query will delete nothing, that is why it is so much faster.

EDIT: I guess I should explain why it will delete nothing. So...

What you wanted to do is actually this:

```
DELETE FROM     t_old a
using           t_old a2
LEFT JOIN       t_prop b ON b.company_id = a2.company_id
where           a.company_id=a2.company_id
and             b.company_id is null;
```

It could be faster, slower or equal in speed to your first query, but it will do the same thing.

Your second query however will only delete rows from `t_old` if there are also rows in `t_prop` with matching `company_id`, because you are making `INNER JOIN` in there. But there is also additional condition `b.company_id is null` with will limit additionally rows in `t_prop` to only those that have this column equal to `NULL`, but `=` operator does not work for `NULL` values and will never evaluate to `true`, so your first condition will always fail if you were to satisfy your second one. Considering there is `AND` between them, both must be satisfied and this is impossible.

What could work and would delete rows in `t_old WHERE company_id IS NULL` that are also in t_prop with same condition satisfied is that:

```
DELETE FROM     t_old a
using           t_prop b 
where           a.company_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b.company_id
and             b.company_id is null;
```

But it still wouldn't do what first query does.